# Selenium Webdriver Eror [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning]

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

Just started to get in to the selenium World via "[Mozilla MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Your_own_automation_environment#Testing_your_element)" and got stuck with an error. Please help to move on forward.

Trying to get text attributes of elements, such p, title, alert... but it doesn't go through.

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
 By = webdriver.By,
 until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
 .forBrowser('chrome')
 .build();

driver.get('http://mdn.github.io/learning-area/tools-testing/cross-browser-testing/accessibility/native-keyboard-accessibility.html');


var button = driver.findElement(By.css('button:nth-of-type(1)'));


button.click();


var alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert.getText().then(function(text) {
 console.log('Alert text is \'' + text + '\'');
})

alert.accept();
```

```
    uptimizators-MacBook-Air:study uptimizator$ node quick_test
(node:1941) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchAlertError: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/Users/uptimizator/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/uptimizator/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:563:13)
    at Executor.execute (/Users/uptimizator/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:489:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (/Users/uptimizator/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:699:17)
(node:1941) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1941) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:1941) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchAlertError: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/Users/uptimizator/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/uptimizator/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:563:13)
    at Executor.execute (/Users/uptimizator/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:489:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (/Users/uptimizator/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:699:17)
(node:1941) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything returns a promise so you should be "await"ing them:

```
; (async function(){
  await driver.get('http://mdn.github.io/learning-area/tools-testing/cross-browser-testing/accessibility/native-keyboard-accessibility.html');

  var button = driver.findElement(By.css('button:nth-of-type(1)'));

  await button.click();

  var alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

  var text = await alert.getText()
  console.log('Alert text is \'' + text + '\'');

  await alert.accept()
})()
```

I don't understand why the docs are wrong, I guess it worked different with old node versions.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. So I am going to study about awaiting and promises.

Comment: You might also want to check out puppeteer which is the more popular way to do this with node.